# Create a dictionary with two distinct set of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Ok, so I have a dictionary of superheroes, with their name as keys, and a dictionary with a bunch of additional info:

```py
heroes = {
    "Superman": {
        "weaknesses": ["kryptonite", "Martha"],
        "alter_ego": "Clark Kent",
        ...},
    "Batman": {
        "weaknesses": [],
        "alter_ego": "Bruce Wayne",
        ...},
    ...
   }
```

As I *may* plan to break into some manors in the city, I'd like to check that the owner of the house is not in fact a hero, or at least have enough info so that I can prepare accordingly.

With this data structure, the search is a bit cumberstone

```py
victim_name = "Clark Kent"

# Check if the victim is not the alterego of an hero
def check_victim_is_hero(victim, heroes):
    alter_egos = [hero["alter_ego"] for  hero in heroes.values()]
    return victim in alter_egos

# I can also get the name of the specific hero
def check_which_hero_is_victim(victim, heroes):
    for hero_name, hero in heroes.items():
        if hero["alter_ego"] == victim:
            return hero_name
```

I can get the weakness by first getting the hero's name, then simply calling `get` on the original dictionary, or change a bit `check_wich_hero_is_victim` to return `hero["weaknesses"]` rather than `hero_name`.

However, either solution forces me to iterate over the dictionary, which as the information I gather grow, get more and more costly.

What I would like is to have an object from which I could call `get` either from superhero or alterego name, with a cost of O(1).

Something like:

```py
heroes_double_index = ...

heroes_double_index.get_from_hero_name("Superman")
>>> {"name": "Superman", "alter_ego": "Clark Kent", "weaknesses":...}

heroes_double_index.get_from_alterego("Clark Kent")
>>> {...} Same dictionary as above
```

My idea for the moment is to have a class which two dictionaries with each set of key that I like:

```py
class DoubleIndexDict:

    # Assuming we get the data as a list of records
    def __init__(self, data):
         self.dict_heroes = {hero["name"]: hero for hero in data}
         self.dict_alterego = {hero["alter_ego"]: hero for hero in data}

    def get_from_hero_name(self, name):
         return self.dict_heroes.get(name)

    def get_from_alter_ego(self, name):
         return self.dict_alterego.get(name)
```

However this does not fully satisfy me, most notably because I can change the values from inside each dictionary without affecting the way the query is done.

```py
heroes_double_index.get_from_hero_name("Captain America")
>>> {"name": "Captain America", "alter_ego": "Steve Rogers"}


# Make the change
heroes_double_index.dict_heroes["Captain America"]["alter_ego"] = "Isaiah Bradley"

# The difference appears inside of the dictionary
heroes_double_index.get_from_hero_name("Captain America")
>>> {"name": "Captain America", "alter_ego": "Isaiah Bradley"}

# But I cannot use the new alterego for my search
heroes_double_index.get_from_alterego("Isaiah Bradley")
>>> None
```

Is there any established and more efficient way to do what I am trying to do in python ?

Comment: I would have personally used a list data structure for the heroes rather than a dictionary like: `[{'name': 'Superman', "weaknesses": ["kryptonite", "Martha"], "alter_ego": "Clark Kent"}, {'name': 'Batman', ...}, ...]` this gets around the double-dict. You could also use classes and have a `Hero` class and put all this logic there since you are already using classes for managing the dicts, then serialize a list of them to a json dict for saving (if you need to). You could even have a `Character` base class and heroes, villains, and civilians inheriting from that with similar logic.

Comment: I think the serialization is a nice way to store the info in a readable, but it  means that I would have to go through the list each time I want an info about either an hero or an alter ego. In this regard, it is less efficient that even a dictionary where at least one key can be accessed without iterating

Comment: You could return hero name in `check_victim_is_hero` that’s truthy.  For the rest, well it depends if you need to serialize your data or not. If not, I’d use actual classes that register facets of their data to central registries.  Like say dict_of_alteregos.  In fact I’d keep a central dict to track all names and point to victims, heros, villains...  Tracking only by branch of persons, as you do in `heroes`, is IMHO very brittle.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be able to update both alter_ego and name simultaneously on O(1) (it wouldn't be a scalable solution for more keys, I think), then you could do something like this:

```
class Heroes:
def __init__(self, data):
    self.id_by_hero = {}
    self.id_by_alter_ego = {}
    self.data = {}

    for i, h in enumerate(data):
        self.id_by_hero[h["name"]] = str(i)
        self.id_by_alter_ego[h["alter_ego"]] = str(i)
        self.data[str(i)] = HeroDict(self, h)

def __getitem__(self, key):
    id = self.id_by_hero.get(key) or self.id_by_alter_ego.get(key)
    return self.data[id] if id else None

def update_key(self, key, old, new):
    if key == "name":
        self.id_by_hero[new] = self.id_by_hero.pop(old)
    if key == "alter_ego":
        self.id_by_alter_ego[new] = self.id_by_alter_ego.pop(old)

class HeroDict(object):
def __init__(self, parent, init=None):
    self.parent = parent
    if init is not None:
        self.__dict__.update(init)

def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    old = self.__dict__[key]
    self.__dict__[key] = value
    self.parent.update_key(key, old, value)

def __repr__(self):
    r = self.__dict__.copy()
    del r['parent']
    return repr(r)
```

by keeping the real data on just one dictionary, you wouldn't have to update both every time you change a value or choose where to get it from. Then, when you update a value, it would call `update_key` and just update the reference.
This way, you'd get:

```
heroes_double_index["Captain America"]
>>> {'name': 'Captain America', 'weaknesses': [], 'alter_ego': 'Steve Rogers'}

heroes_double_index["Captain America"]["alter_ego"] = "Isaiah Bradley"

heroes_double_index["Captain America"]
>>> {'name': 'Captain America', 'weaknesses': [], 'alter_ego': 'Isaiah Bradley'}

heroes_double_index["Isaiah Bradley"]
>>> {'name': 'Captain America', 'weaknesses': [], 'alter_ego': 'Isaiah Bradley'}
```